# How do i set up WMI in c++?

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, wmi, wmi-service

I am trying to get the process of the running service by using WMI. But i am confused as to how use WMI.

i think that using this method will work 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller.servicename%28v=vs.71%29

But i a dont know how to set up WMI in order to use this

I know i need to do this but am not sure where to go from there

```
 HRESULT hres(CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_MULTITHREADED));
     // Set general COM security levels
hres = CoInitializeSecurity(
    NULL,
    -1,                             // COM authentication
    NULL,                           // Authentication services
    NULL,                           // Reserved
    RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_DEFAULT,      // Default authentication
    RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_IMPERSONATE,    // Default Impersonation
    NULL,                           // Authentication Info
    EOAC_NONE,                      // Additional capabiliteis
    NULL                            // Reserved
    );
```

Comment: The service name of the service application that we are using

Comment: RTFM: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394558%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

[EnumServicesStatusEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682640.aspx) will give you (among other things) ProcessId's of all active services. Compare that with the ID of the current process to find the one that matches. Along with the ProcessID, you'll get two names for each service: the service name and the display name. I'm not sure *which* of those you want, but presumably one of the two.